# How to color just the `\"`?

Tags: color, typography, languages, accents

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{\"\!\!\!{\textcolor{black}{o}}} %<-- ?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make this easier? Also work in other accents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accents over nothing are raised by 1ex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\cu}[2][red]{% colored umlaut
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{
    \halign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \textcolor{#1}{\"{}}\cr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-1ex}
      #2\cr
    }
  }%
}
\newcommand{\cc}[2][red]{% colored cedilla
 \leavevmode
 \begingroup
 \ooalign{\hfil#2\hfil\cr\hfil\textcolor{#1}{\c{}}\hfil\cr}%
 \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\cu{O}zg\cu{u}r \"Ozg\"ur \cc[blue]{C}\cc{c}\cc{S}\cc{s} \c{C}\c{c}\c{S}\c{s}

\bigskip

\LARGE \cu{O}zg\cu{u}r \"Ozg\"ur

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg, funziona alla grande.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps just wrap it in a macro, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}

\newcommand{\oo}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}\"{}}o}
\newcommand{\cc}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}\c{#1}}#1}

\begin{document}
    L\oo\oo{k} at this: \cc{c} and \cc{s}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\c{c}` (ç) and `\c{s}` (ş) bad working.

Comment: `\newcommand{\cc}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}\c{#1}}#1}` and using `\cc{c}`/`\cc{s}` in the doc? It prints the black `c` on top of the red one, not sure it that would affect anything in your document

Comment: Your solution provided me with new information

Answer (score 8):

You could use `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\my}[2]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{1.1pt}{\color{red}#2}{\color{black}#1}}
\newcommand{\myc}[1]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.8pt}{#1}{\color{red}\c{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    S\my{o}{\"}\"{o}mething \c{c}\myc{c}o\c{s}\myc{s}a
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\c{c}` (ç) and `\c{s}` (ş) bad working.

Comment: @Özgür See my renewed answer, this is the best I can do.

Comment: Your solution provided me with new information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **dirty** solution, but it might work **for weird accents** as well:

Usually it is easier to get the letter without the dots than the dots without the letter. Therefore you can draw the complete letter in red, then draw the non-accent part over it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \textcolor{red}{ö}%% make a red ö
    \llap{o}%% print a black o over it
\end{document}
```

It doesn't really look good at lower zoom levels, but it might be useful if you don't know how to compose the character.

[image: result]